# my User Card looks like it's cut at bottom in FF3.6

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-card

- For the reference: [supported browser list - revisions history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/71208/revisions)

**update** bug explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105442/my-user-card-looks-like-its-cut-at-bottom-in-ff3-6/105523#105523) looks fixed now. Problematic content mentioned below doesn't trigger user card popup anymore (tested with FF3.6 and IE7 / WinXP)

---

In Firefox 3.6 (Win XP and Win 7), my user card now looks like it's cut at bottom, as shown in red below. Note in IE 9 it looks OK. Also, the effect goes away after reloading the page in Firefox and returns back after *Shift+Reload*.

Could it be modified to show properly in Firefox without reload, as marked green - ie with dark-gray border at bottom?
[image: red - bad, green - good]

I noticed this issue with *About Me* section content in my profile set to show combined SO flair:

- `<a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/20c1f9efd12440c6b25b566dee0836f6">
  <img src="http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/20c1f9efd12440c6b25b566dee0836f6.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for gnat on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for gnat on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites">
  </a>`

---

Note the issue goes away when I add long enough summary to *About Me*. I plan to keep it as-is for a while just in case if needed to reproduce the problem. If needed, here's the link to one of my answers to look at it: [link to example answer with my user card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320546/how-jls-corresponds-to-sun-javac-why-they-do-not-match/7329771#7329771)

Comment: I don't see this.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on IE 9 or FF 3.6.

Comment: @MatthewRead FireFox 3.6 - on Win 7 and WinXP... woo-hoo in IE 9 / Win 7 it looks as I want it. Will update the question

Comment: I see it only on the first few views of the card... then it eventually shows the full card.  Maybe it's due to it using AJAX, the fact that you actually don't have anything in your summary but an image (and they are not displayed in the card but fooled the length detection), or a combination of both.

Comment: @JeffMercado thanks for the tip _reload_ in Firefox did that trick to me too - I'll update the answer

Comment: @gnat: You don't necessarily have to reload.  When you first hover, it may show as cutoff.  But if you move away (and it disappears) and you hover over it again after a while, it will show in full (at least, that's what I've observed on FF6.0.2).

Comment: @JeffMercado confirmed - in my case, _re-hover_ fixes this, too

Comment: Hmm, [the supported browser list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) still lists FF 3.6 but I wonder if that's true anymore, since the current version is now 6.0.2.  FF4 should be supported since it's so recent (5 and 6 might as well be the same version) but not sure about 3.6.

Comment: I updated the browser list -- best guess is that 3.6 is unsupported.

Comment: @MatthewRead I see thanks - I set _last updated_ today in [supported browser list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) (in suggested edits queue). Rev 17 update makes a perfect answer to my question btw :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual bug here was that you were even considered to be having enough content for a popup at all. Since images are removed for the popup, all you ended up with was an empty link, in other words: Nothing.

Having a *de facto* empty text may have caused CSS issues there (I don't have a FF3 around anymore to test); but having that empty content shouldn't happen in the first place. This is fixed in the next build, after which (unless you edit your profile) you won't have a popup anymore.

Comment: that makes good sense. When do you expect next build to be deployed? would be interesting to test it with my current content.

Comment: It has been built in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3.5 is probably not supported anymore: [supported browsers list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) is updated to reflect that (rev 17)